# How do I ensure my new 18+ topic website is classified and registered correctly and appropriately, for its 18+ content?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, best-practices, filtering, adult-content, protection

## The situation and website

A new (static) information website will refer to adult and sexual matters, but not contain explicit sexual material. So for example, it might mention in passing *"Sexual activity is permitted upstairs at club X"* or *"kinks such as XYZ are accepted at venue Y"* on its main page, but wouldn't show images or explicit descriptions of such things.

There's **nothing** on the site that should be relevant to **anyone** under 18.

For 18+ it's more the adult themed subject matter, than explicit sexual detailed descriptions, that is a concern. The site is small (3-6 pages, mostly static with periodic updates by owner/manager) and mainly informational. It won't contain user content for a while if ever. But it's conceivable that over time a (separate) textual feedback page may be added, and if so, the feedback might be a concern for being more explicit/descriptive.

If it matters, the site is narrowly focused in the UK, and its focus is summary information and FAQ about events and clubs in a specific area, that allow varying degrees of intimate conduct.

The website also doesn't need age verification, and doesn't (wont ever) store, record, click-track, link-track, or log any personal data or users actions, nor any persistent data or cookies. Privacy. Even if it had a feedback page it would be anonymous feedback retyped with any references to personal material excluded. It isn't yet known if it'll ultimately be hosted in or out of the UK or EU.

Either way it should be hidden by Google Childsafe, and probably also registered with (or tagged for) the top few/major child content filters - especially those used in the UK? -  although probably right now the tag would be for mature themes rather than actual displayed sexual content, if that matters. And anything else that lets it be correctly classified and better recognised for filtering/displaying/linking to/blocking/warning/parental controls.

Also may be relevant, they are not going the route of having an "Are you 18+" enter/leave page. There isn't any practical way to verify the answer without a lot of personal data and site hardening that they have no intention of getting into, and they don't want to mislead people to expect 18+ checks in the actual site itself when it can't/won't realistically be provided.  Especially as it's a static informational site with no pornographic content anyway, so it needs to reduce access barriers to its intended users. So handling it at the search and content awareness level seems a good balanced approach.

**All those involved are very focused on child safety, content appropriateness, privacy, and reducing distress by accidental discovery.** It's a distinctive topic with its likely search terms also not that usual, so someone looking on an unfiltered/explicit-allowed connection or search, would probably find it on page 1. They want it to be findable by adults who enable explicit searches and don't have filtered connections), but safeguard people who have barred explicit material, or have ISP or domestic filtering on their connections.  **They have requested that whatever is needed, is done, and any other advice on doing it correctly.**

## Past questions on S.E.

I've never had this kind of need before. Past questions on the topic here and StackOverflow often recommend child protection systems that no longer exist, and are either more narrow or off taarget fpor my needs.  For example, they want to *use* a filter (rather than get *added* to one), **or** they don't give much detail how to do this correctly or at all, **or** don't make clear if there are UK specific schemes to consider too (as well as global/US ones), **or** are outdated.

Ive also found a lot of child protection systems websites mentioned in past answers here and on StackOverflow no longer exist, or don't accept new data.

## Aspects of the question that I've discovered in researching it

While the question is narrow, I can see it is likely to be like IT security, layered and not just a single place to go, or a single thing to do. So below are some of the possible considerations that this question has already turned up in my research, so that answers can be more comprehensive and relevant.

1. **Well known/major schemes:** What should I register it with, as a bare minimum, and what else might I consider optionally, to provide sensible coverage with public website-info and categorising schemes, blocklists, internet safety registrars, Google, etc?
2. **Same but UK specific:** Given the site, its managers, its owners, and its focus are all totally UK-centric, are there any specific internet safety schemes widely used in the UK, that it's important or worth registering with, even if they aren't big in a more global sense?
   - Related, does the the adult nature influence hosting location, provided a proposed host's T&C allow it?
3. **Cost:** I'd assume that registering a site for child safety and mature content wouldnt cost, but you never know. Is restricting to non-charging schemes (hopefully all, or almost all) going to be reasonable? Its a non profit thing, not commercially funded.
4. **Meta tags and HTTP headers:** What are the main tags that are needed in the <head>/HTTP? I assume *<meta name="rating" content="mature">* or similar, are there others that ought to be used as well? Or more sophisticated tagging schemes now more widely used?
   - Related, is there a reference document to clarify intended significance of "mature" vs "adult" vs "restricted", to check whether mature (or other values) is the appropriate classification? Can't find *anything* describing this tag's options, anywhere at all. Must be some RFC surely!
   - Related again, is there any "best practice" guidance on snippet/follow, or does other classification mean that snippets and following aren't really issues?
5. **Website size/style implications:** Often smaller sites dont need all the setup amd support and infrastructure of larger/commercial ones. It could be there are things that are best practice but honestly, overdoing it for this scale of site, given its small size (4-6 pages), its intent (informational not sales), its ownership (home project not business), not aggressively promoted via SEO, and mostly static textual content?
6. **Adding a feedback page later on:** If the website as a whole mentions mature themes but doesnt contain explicit material, but later adds a feedback page that might contain explicit textual feedback, what are the implications and best practice actions? Does it require moving the whole site to a "higher level" of safety, or does changing just the registration+tags for that one page suffice?
   - Related, does the answer vary if the user feedback text is kept to a feedback page vs. included lower down on the home page?

## My question

**What is the right way according to current best practices, and acting as a responsible web designer/owner in 2022, to get my site classified and registered correctly and appropriately, for its 18+ content?**

Help very appreciated. As you can imagine, most content awareness and control informational web resources/pages link to articles about *avoiding* such content as a parent or web user, or *avoiding* your site being wrongly filtered as a webmaster. Not actual coverage of how to assess the level of adult-ness of your content and get it safer.

Comment: Classified by who?

Comment: Like I ask in the Q, _"What should I register it with, as a bare minimum, and what else might I consider optionally, to provide sensible coverage*_. It's an important part of it.

Comment: There's at least *nine* questions here. That is not a good fit for this format. Please narrow it down to one question (which should probably be the one in bold since that is the main goal of this question).

Comment: On top of John's comment I would also add, please make sure to have the smallest possible question(s), because here you have a big blob of text that takes minutes just to read... And parts of it do not add value to the question, like the last paragraph seems redundant. But at least kudos for the title that is descriptive.